# Ruby string interpolation not working when called from an included file

Tags: ruby

I have two files: `urls.rb` and `testcase.rb`. `urls.rb` has the following:

```
$event = "/sendmessage/#{id}"
```

The `id` in the url is generated in `testcase.rb`. This is the code in `testcase.rb`:

```
require 'urls.rb'

id = 100
puts $event
```

I am seeing the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `id' for main:Object (NameError)
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: you declaring `Id = 100 `or `id = 100`, because its different...

Comment: Sorry, ignore my typo. The variable name in both the files is same.               
urls.rb has the folloing $event = "/sendmessage/#{id}"                                     
testcase.rb has the following require 'urls.rb' id=100 puts $event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables like `id` cannot be called across files. Their scopes are limited within a file. In order to use it, you have to assign `id` in the same file as it is used. Furthermore, your assignment of `id` after requiring `'urls.rb'` is meaningless.

Comment: Or use an object with global scope instead like a constant or global variable instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are attempting to use `id` in `urls.rb` before it has been defined by `testcase.rb`. Your code is functionally equivalent to the following:

```
$event = "/sendmessage/#{id}"
id = 100
puts $event
```

This does not work because you are attempting to call `id` before it has been defined. You must define the variable first:

```
id = 100
$event = "/sendmessage/#{id}"
puts $event
```

Here it works because you have defined `id` *before* you're trying to call it.

When troubleshooting a problem like this, consider how it would have to work if you were not separating it into different files.

So without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish, just make sure you have defined a variable *before* you try to call it.

Comment: Defining `id` before calling `require 'urls.rb'` results in the same error.